# dojo How Tree insert data to children?

Tags: dojo

hi i want to insert data to children to Tree.but I want to put the data.for example i want to update children[0] information.Rather than creating a new one I'd like to update the existing data.

my Tree.json

```
 {
    "name": "SCATTER/BUBBLE CHART",
    "id": "SCATTERBUBBLE",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Series",
            "id": "SERIES",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name" : "Data:X",
                    "id" : "DX"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Data:Y",
                    "id" : "DY"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "XAxis",
            "id": "X"
        },
        {
            "name": "YAxis",
            "id": "Y"
        }
    ]
}
```

if i click button,i want to result

```
{
    "name": "SCATTER/BUBBLE CHART",
    "id": "SCATTERBUBBLE",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Series",
            "id": "SERIES",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name" : "Data:X",
                    "id" : "DX"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Data:Y",
                    "id" : "DY"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Data:Z",
                    "id" : "DZ"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "XAxis",
            "id": "X"
        },
        {
            "name": "YAxis",
            "id": "Y"
        },
                    {
            "name": "ZAxis",
            "id": "Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

i don't know update children tree ask for advice

Answer (score 0):

Use `node.item` to get the store item object which has created the node. I hope you have the node object. For instance if you want to get the root node of your tree :-

`var rootNode = dijit.byId("treeID").attr("rootNode");`

After you get the node's item object you may update any of its attributes and your store will be modified. Your store should also extend "dojo/store/Observable", so that your tree gets updated with the changes to store.